# DRY for Rust conditional compilation with features

Tags: rust, compilation

My library has several features, say `F1`, `F2`, `F3`, `F4`,.. and only one of them can be active at a time. These features are further classified as types `A`, `B`, `C`, so for example, features `F1` and `F2` are of type `A`, `F3`, `F4` are of type `B` and so on.

I have several occurrences of such code (in the library)

```rust
#[cfg(any(feature = "F1", feature = "F2"))]
fn do_onething_for_type_A(... ) {
```

```rust
// repeating same cfg predicate as above
#[cfg(any(feature = "F1", feature = "F2"))]
fn do_another_thing_for_type_A(... ) {
```

```rust
#[cfg(any(feature = "F3", feature = "F4"))]
fn do_onething_for_type_B(... ) {
```

Is there a way to write the above `cfg` predicates concisely so that I don't have to mention each feature in the `#[cfg(any(..` every time I have that condition? Verbosity is not the only issue. Every time I introduce a new feature, say `F5` which is of type, say, `A`, I have to update the occurrences of line `#[cfg(any(feature = "F1", feature = "F2"))]` to `#[cfg(any(feature = "F1", feature = "F2", feature = "F5"))]`.

My first thought was to *create* an attribute based on the feature and then use the attribute as below but seems I can't do that.

```rust
#[cfg(any(feature = "F1", feature = "F2"), typeA)]
#[cfg(any(feature = "F3", feature = "F4"), typeB)]

#[typeA]
fn do_onething_for_type_A(... ) {...}

#[typeA]
fn do_another_thing_for_type_A(... ) {

#[typeB]
fn do_onething_for_type_B(... ) {
```

Declaring a new feature for types `A`, `B`, `C` is my last resort.

Comment: you could move all code that require type A into a file and include this mod/file only if the features you want are here

Comment: @Stargateur Thanks. That won't be easy in my case as the usages are spread across different modules, macros, and functions.

Comment: Careful, there's currently [no way to tell cargo](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/2980) about mutually exclusive features (features where only one is allowed at a time).

This means that you can end up hairy situations in a project with multiple crates that each depend on your crate. Cargo may activate multiple features and it's difficult to get it not to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`cfg_aliases`](https://crates.io/crates/cfg_aliases) crate, although it requires adding a build script.

```
// Cargo.toml
[build-dependencies]
cfg_aliases = "0.1.0"
```

```
// build.rs
use cfg_aliases::cfg_aliases;

fn main() {
    // Setup cfg aliases
    cfg_aliases! {
        type_a: { any(feature = "F1", feature = "F2") },
        type_b: { any(feature = "F3", feature = "F4") },
        type_c: { feature = "F5" },
    }
}
```

```
#[cfg(type_a)]
fn do_onething_for_type_A(... ) {...}

#[cfg(type_a)]
fn do_another_thing_for_type_A(... ) {

#[cfg(type_b)]
fn do_onething_for_type_B(... ) {
```

Alternatively you can define macros [like Tokio does](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/blob/master/tokio/src/macros/cfg.rs).

```
macro_rules! cfg_type_a {
    ($($item:item)*) => {
        $(
            #[cfg(any(feature = "F1", feature = "F2"))]
            $item
        )*
    }
}
```

```
cfg_type_a! {
    fn do_onething_for_type_A() {
        ...
    }
}
cfg_type_b! {
    fn do_onething_for_type_B() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that the macro-based approach can cause trouble for any of users of the library using the CLion IDE. When using that IDE, you have to enable

> Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Rust > Expand declarative macros: Use experimental engine

to get type completion for things defined behind macros such as above.